# Pentaho mondrian cube main sql query

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, mondrian, pentaho-cde

I had a problem while programming a schema in mondrian. The thing is that I want to filter the main query inside the  tag of the cube so that it can only access the dimensions taking into account the logged in user. Is there any way to get that value dynamically and add it to the query?

```
    <Cube>
        <Annotations>
        </Annotations>
        <View>
            <SQL dialect="generic">
                <
                select a.* 
                  from xxxxx a where (here is where i want to obtain the username value)
                >
            </SQL>  
        </View>
```

I tried to search in several webpages but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

It's only have Parameter function of MDX Expression, but not find how to create a dynamic sql.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).